# PLSQL printing Author with Publisher

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to write a PLSQL block to display details of books along with their Author and Publisher.
problem statement is as follow:
Use String functions to display only the first 10 letters of column 'Title'  and Sort the result set based on 'Title' in ascending order.
Schema details are given below:-

Table Name       Columns

1.author         authorid, firstname, lastname

2.book       author_id, bookid, publisherid, title

3.publisher  publisherid, publishername

Output format is as follows:

BOOKID.............TITLE.............publisher.............Author

639163050...........10 Years o...........Prentice Hall...........Paul Deitel

330895717...........African Fo...........Prentice Hall...........Tem Nieto

my output is coming the same as required but somehow hackerrank is not accepting it. Please refer the code below and help if you can:

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
cursor c is

select * from book b 
left join author on authorid=author_id 
left join publisher p on b.publisherid=p.publisherid
order by title asc;

begin

 dbms_output.put_line('BOOKID'||'...........'||'TITLE'||'...........'||'publisher'||'...........'||'Author');

for i in c loop


  dbms_output.put_line(i.bookid||'...........'||substr(i.title,1,10)||'...........'||i.publishername||'...........'||concat(i.firstname||' ',i.lastname));

   end loop;

  end;
  /
```

Comment: Hackerrank is very fussy about matching the exact format it requires. Maybe you are missing a dot or something.

Comment: Perhaps terminating that PL/SQL block with a slash `/`?

Comment: @Littlefoot I have done that. I just didn't write it here.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Thanks. It was indeed a missing dot. I can not believe it. I wasted too much time on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbms_output.put_line('BOOKID'||'.............'||'TITLE'||'.............'||'publisher'||'.............'||'Author');
```

There are 13 dots in between and you have entered 11 :)